# Script ends after switch function (php)

Tags: php

I have this script, it rotates the image if its rotated. However, it ends after switch function. It doesnt echo "success";. Is there any way to prevent it to stop the script ?

```
$exif = exif_read_data('img/picture.png');
$ort = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
    switch($ort)
    {
        case 1: // nothing
        break;

        case 2: // horizontal flip
            $image->flipImage($public,1);
        break;

        case 3: // 180 rotate left
            $image->rotateImage($public,180);
        break;

        case 4: // vertical flip
            $image->flipImage($public,2);
        break;

        case 5: // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
            $image->flipImage($public, 2);
                $image->rotateImage($public, -90);
        break;

        case 6: // 90 rotate right
            $image->rotateImage($public, -90);
        break;

        case 7: // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
            $image->flipImage($public,1);   
            $image->rotateImage($public, -90);
        break;

        case 8:    // 90 rotate left
            $image->rotateImage($public, 90);
        break;
    }


echo "success";
```

Comment: Where is `echo "Success";`? I can't see it. Add in question.

Comment: you need to echo "success"  or prevent from echo "success"

Comment: It means you have errors on your server side, I would suggest to check for php errors